# Match regex until the first occurrence of special character '->'

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-negation, regex-group, regex-greedy

I am a newbie to regexp and was trying to match the expression until a special character/s. If the matches exist before the special character then return it otherwise return nothing.

Here is the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/gF2hZ2/36).

My goal is to return the match if found before the '->' special character otherwise return nothing. It should not return the matches after the '->' special char.

Regexp: `/()()(\[[^\]]+\])\s*(-[->])(.*)/g` // In third group actual result will be returned

For example data:

[AAA] -> [BBB] -> [CCC] // In this case needs to match [AAA]

AAA -> [BBB] -> [CCC] // In this case do not return [BBB], instead return nothing as before special char '->', no matchng is there.

Please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just add ^ at the beginning. Also you can delete 2 empty () groups. Here is simplified version: https://regex101.com/r/6NcJBF/1

Comment: Thanks all for your valuable replies. Hi Emma, Tried your first Link seems it serves my purpose but I need to add two empty () for some purpose. If I add it breaking the matches, Could you please suggest. [Link](https://regex101.com/r/j3UP8M/3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this regex

```
^\[(.*?)\] ->
```

and capture group 1 (inside the braces).

[See this regex101 test](https://regex101.com/r/0RjD1l/1)

Comment: Thank you, Bob, It worked for me by tweaking as per my need.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
^\[[^\]]+\](?=\h*->)
```

**Explanation:**

```
^               # beginning of string
  \[            # opening squarre bracket
    [^\]]+      # 1 or more any character that is not closiing bracket
  \]            # closing bracket
  (?=           # start positive lookahead, make sure we have after:
    \h*         # 0 or more horizontal spaces
    ->          # literally ->
  )             # end lookahead
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gF2hZ2/38)

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand the problem, just copying a few guessworks in here, that might get you closer to what you're trying to accomplish:

```
^()()((\[[^\]]*\]))\s*->(.*)
```

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/uYbnYQ/1)

```
()()(\[[^\]]+\])\s*->(\s*\[[^\]]+\]\s*->\s*\[[^\]]+\])
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/YFYpHu/1)

```
()()(\[[^\]\r\n]+\])\s*->\s*(\[[^\]\r\n]+\]\s*->\s*\[[^\]\r\n]+\])
```

#### [Demo 3](https://regex101.com/r/xMJQXe/1)

```js
const regex = /^()()((\[[^\]]*\]))\s*(->)(.*)/gm;
const str = `[AAA] -> [BBB] -> [CCC]
AAA -> [BBB] -> [CCC]`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Emma, Informative links, thanks for sharing it.